# Jmeter response assertion

Tags: jmeter

I have two HTTP requests and the output of first one result value should match with the second request output value..if not matched then fail..

i want to do this check in response assertion..

i have done below steps:

a) Using Regular Expression Extractor i have extracted the value from first HTTP request

b) Added Response Assertion for second request and now how to compare that value with the response of second request

How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

[image: JMeter Response Assertion Contains]

If "Request 2" response will contain the variable from the Regular Expression Extractor - it will pass, otherwise it will fail.

Replace the `${Variable_From_The_Regular_Expression_Extractor}` with what you have in the "Name of created variable" in the Regular Expression Extractor.

References:

- [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)
- [Response Assertions in JMeter 3.2 - New and Improved](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri... First request result is ->
es_queryETime":0,"es_totalResults":190,"es_Type":"estimated"        
Second request result is -> 
"node":122,"count":190,"logicT":"lkf"

now i want to match "es_totalResults":190 to "count":190   ( value of es_totalResults and count  i.e 190)

i have extracted from first request "es_totalResults":([0-9a-z-])*+

and trying to put the same in patterns to test panel of Response assetion in second request "es_totalResults":([0-9a-z-])*+

it shows failed.

can you help please.

Comment: Go for 2 [JSON Extractors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to fetch `total_results` form 1st request and `count` from the 2nd request, the relevant [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries would be `$..es_totalResults` and `$..count` correspondingly. Then compare 2 variables using the Response Assertion.  See [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) article for more details.